# Copying files from vhd-disk to Blob container in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I have vhd-disk connected to Azure VM and would like to copy files from the vhd-disk to Blob container to further process them in HDInsight. What is the easiest  way to do this?

Comment: This should be posted to ServerFault, not StackOverflow. It's not a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Copy Blob to copy the files from VHD to Azure storage account as blobs. You can run copy blob commands on PowerShell or Azure CLI inside your VM to copy the data. If you are using a Windows VM, you could leverage the AzCopy command line utility within the VM. See links below for references:

Azure PowerShell - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-powershell-guide-full/

Azure CLI - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-azure-cli/

AzCopy - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/